# Is there a difference in GdipSaveImageToFile between Xp and Windows 7? - c#

Tags: c#

Using this to save an image between the 2 Os's i see different values in tags of the saved image particularly with the photometric values.

The image format is TIFF

Windows 7:
Photometric (1 Short): Palette

XP:
Photometric (1 Short): MinIsBlack

The image when viewed thru photoshop is different and when converting to pdf the windows 7 image is white on black rather then b on w

Steps to reproduce:
-scan image using TWAIN scanner and save image using above said function.

I used a codeproject solution for this testing. 
[This TWAIN project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx)

Save image using GdipSaveImageToFile on XP and win 7

Observe the diff in image using photoshop and view tag difference using 'ASTiffTagviewer'

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, yes there is a difference.  I am trying to save a PNG from VB6 using the GDI+ API, the classid gives an error under win7 but works fine under XP.  Interesting, because if I use the same code for JPG it works on both OS's.  The classid must be different for PNG files and I assume the same for TIFF.  Does anyone have the classid for win7?

Another solution for VB6 is in referencing the WIAAUT.DLL which ships with Win7 (but must be added to XP in the WinSys32 directory and regsvr'd) it provides TIFF, GIF, PNG, JPG funcionality, here's a link.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29